# jTables Filtering for PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

jTable (www.jtable.org) has great references to Filtering on its website, but its for ASP.NET. I require it to use for PHP, but sadly the documentation made no mention of the APIs for filtering except for the sample ASP.NET server side file.

Anyway, jTables uses:

```
//Re-load records when user click 'load records' button.
    $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load', {
            Name: $('#Name').val(),
            Branch: $('#Branch').val()
        });
    });
```

I can see that I can pass values to the server using the Name and branch, but I don't know how to catch that on the PHP code so I can do a `WHERE` on my mysql code.

Comment: Found it. All I needed was a simple `$_POST["Name"]` and it worked!

Comment: `@marche` where you have create `$_POST["Name"]`..? please put code that fulfill your requirement for reference purpose, i really need that code.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Load person list from server
$('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load', { Age: 78 });

//Get records from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE Age = '" . $_POST["Age"] . "';");
```

Comment: where you put the query on the php file?

Comment: Njoroge, your code is basically OK, but I think a warning is in order for the classic [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability created by this code. Always sanitize (check) all data that comes from the client as it can be spoofed (forged). All of it. Always. The minimum you can do here is i.e. parse the $_POST["Age"] into an integer. Yes, it will die (blow up) doing so if there is no integer in the data, but this should never happen and it will prevent execution of an arbitrary SQL query.
The example as-is enables hackers to read, write and drop your database l